# Custom adapter not showing data in tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs, android-recyclerview

I have an activity with tabs, in each tab I load the same fragment to show different lists of data.

Although it's the same fragment and therefor the adapter is the same, and the information is loaded in the same way one of the fragment's `RecyclerView` doesn't show the information.

[image]  [image]

I know the data is getting there because I debugged it and also because otherwise it would be showing a text in the screen saying there is no data to show.

I have 4 or 5 tabs, the first two always load just fine. But on the others it seems like the `onCreateView` isn't completely executed.

This is called from the `onCreateView`.

```
if (offers.size() != 0)
    noOffers.setVisibility(View.GONE); //this gets execute, it hide some text that otherwise would be on the left image
else
    content.setVisibility(View.GONE);

this.offers = offers;

MyOffersAdapter adapter = new MyOffersAdapter(getActivity(), this.offers, user);
rvOffers.setAdapter(adapter);
rvOffers.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity())); //this part is getting executed in all the tabs
```

Although it reaches the last line neither `onCreateViewHolder` nor `onBindViewHolder`of the adapter get execute for the tabs beyond the second one.

This is the code I'm using to create the after setting the tabs:

```
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
tabs.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
});
```

Is there a way I can force those methods to be executed when the tab is clicked? Or what am I configuring wrong?

Comment: Post your fragment class and adapter full code.

Comment: @FAT just did so

Comment: Before creating instance of adapter make sure your offers list size > 0. and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after setting adapter.

Comment: @FAT that didn't changed anything, `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder` are getting executed for the other fragments but not for this one